# How to set the doctype of an XMLDOMDocument?

Tags: html, doctype, msxml

How can i set the `doctype` of an `DOMDocument60` object?

For example i try:

```
IXMLDOMDocument60 doc = new DOMDocument60();
doc.doctype.name = "html";
```

except that `IXMLDOMDocumentType.name` is **read-only**:

```
IXMLDOMDocumentType = interface(IXMLDOMNode)
{
   ['{2933BF8B-7B36-11D2-B20E-00C04F983E60}']
   string Get_name();
   ...
   property String name read Get_name;
}
```

and `IXMLDOMDocument60.doctype` is **read-only**:

```
IXMLDOMDocument = interface(IXMLDOMNode)
{
   ['{2933BF81-7B36-11D2-B20E-00C04F983E60}']
   IXMLDOMDocumentType Get_doctype();
   ...
   property IXMLDOMDocumentType doctype read Get_doctype;
}
```

So how can i set the `doctype` of an XML document?

---

**Bonus Question:** How can i *create* an `DOMDocument60` object with a specified `doctype`?

---

**Note:** You see no mention of XSLT, because there is none. i'm building an HTML DOM tree in MSXML.

Comment: You may use `loadXML("<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE root_element SYSTEM "DTD_location"><root_element/>" )` and go from there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [perfomance reasons](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/marcelolr/2009/11/30/msxml-xhtml-dtds-making-the-web-better/) and [security reasons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754611(v=vs.85).aspx), Microsoft does not usually allow `<!DOCTYPE>` (aka the [Document Type Definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-docent)). Because of this, you must use the `loadXML` method to set the `<!DOCTYPE>`. So, it cannot be set after a document has been created or imported.

On top of that, because of default security settings in [MSXML6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762632(v=vs.85).aspx), you normally cannot import XML that has a `<!DOCTYPE>`. So, you must disable the [`ProhibitDTD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762632(v=vs.85).aspx) setting on the object.

**Edit:** You should know that [HTML5 is **not** XML](http://w3c.github.io/html/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml). Also, the `<!DOCTYPE>` is [considered optional for XHTML5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/xhtml.html#writing-xhtml-documents).

First, let's start with the desired output.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html />
```

Based on the syntax, I'm assuming you are using C# and have added a reference to `msxml6.dll`. The following code will allow you to create those two processing instructions.

```
MSXML2.DOMDocument60 doc  = new MSXML2.DOMDocument60();

// Disable validation when importing the XML
doc.validateOnParse = false;
// Enable the ability to import XML that contains <!DOCTYPE>
doc.setProperty("ProhibitDTD", false);
// Perform the import
doc.loadXML("<!DOCTYPE html><html />");
// Display the imported XML
Console.WriteLine(doc.xml);
```

Here's a copy of the code written in VBScript, as well.

```
Set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")

' Disable validation when importing the XML
doc.validateOnParse = False
' Enable the ability to import XML that contains <!DOCTYPE>
doc.setProperty "ProhibitDTD", false
' Perform the import
doc.loadXML "<!DOCTYPE html><html />"
' Display the imported XML
WScript.Echo objXML.xml
```

Finally, here's a copy of the code written in C++.

```
#include <comutil.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "comsuppw.lib")
#include <msxml6.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "msxml6.lib")

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    VARIANT_BOOL success = VARIANT_TRUE;
    // IXMLDOMDocument2 is needed for setProperty
    IXMLDOMDocument2 *doc;

    // Initialize COM
    hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Create the object
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_DOMDocument60, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IXMLDOMDocument2, (void**)&doc);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Disable validation when importing the XML
            hr = doc->put_validateOnParse(VARIANT_FALSE);
            // Enable the ability to import XML that contains <!DOCTYPE>
            hr = doc->setProperty(_bstr_t(L"ProhibitDTD"), _variant_t(VARIANT_FALSE));
            // Perform the import
            hr = doc->loadXML(_bstr_t(L"<!DOCTYPE html><html />"), &success);
            // Retrieve the XML
            _bstr_t output{};
            hr = doc->get_xml(output.GetAddress());
            // Display the imported XML
            MessageBoxW(NULL, output, NULL, 0);
        }
        // Cleanup COM
        CoUninitialize();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My issue is now that i have a `DOMDocument` in memory, i need to save it to a stream using some particular encoding. `IXMLDOMDocument.Save` writes the document to a stream using the encoding specified in the `doctype`. Which means i need to be able to change the doctype to set the encoding.

Comment: As far as I am aware, encoding isn't declared in the doctype. https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations

Comment: It absolutely is declared in the doctype. https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd. Which is why msxml uses the encoding in the doctype. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms753769(v=vs.85)

Comment: Pretty sure we're talking about two different things. My answer refers to the "Document Type Definition" `<!DOCTYPE>` not the "XML Declaration" `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`.

Comment: I was referring to the *"Document Type Declaration"* (or *doctype*, if you will). Of course: HTML is not XML; and i was referring to XML - not HTML.

Comment: Then, I'm definitely confused. Reading over https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms753769(v=vs.85)#remarks it states `Character encoding is based on the encoding attribute in the XML declaration, such as <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>. When no encoding attribute is specified, the default setting is UTF-8.` So, I don't see where the _doctype_ comes into play for encoding. Even the XML specification you linked https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charencoding references the _XML declaration_, not the _doctype_ for character encoding.

Comment: Exactly, the doctype: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Shift-JIS"?>`. Problem is how to set that, the doctype, **after** i have a document in memory.

Comment: Just for clarification, that's the _XML declaration_, but to answer your question, that's a whole other can of worms. Can I get you post a new question to stackoverflow and link it here? My answer was specifically for `<!DOCTYPE>`. It's more complicated than a comment can answer.

Comment: It's an XML *Document Type Declaration*, which we will shorten to *"doctype"*; since it doesn't affect anything in any way, and nobody is confused by it at all, and it's the term for it.

Comment: Regardless, my answer was for `<!DOCTYPE>`, not `<?xml version="1.0">`. If you feel my answer is incorrect, feel free to unmark it as the answer. Dealing with `<?xml version="1.0">` is far different than `<!DOCTYPE>`. I will try to add an answer for `<?xml version="1.0">` when I can.